# How to select few columns from different database tables considering some conditions?

Tags: mysql

My website is called "Informational System of Hostelry Rooms".

I apply one database creating 6 tables. The first three represents properties of hostelry room: "storeys", "places", "type". The first one represents the storey. The second one the quantity of places per one number. The third one characterizes other characteristics. Every row of every first three tables has own price.

```
$CR1="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS storeys(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, characteristic VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE, price FLOAT(10))";
$CR2="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, characteristic VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE, price FLOAT(10))";
$CR3="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, characteristic VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE, price FLOAT(10))";
```

When the user decides to make an order, the program makes a sum of three prices by three parameters of the room to get the price of living in the room for 1 day.

I've cared about the data of clients:

```
$CR4="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, pib VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE, phone VARCHAR(30))";
```

After the calculation of the price of living in the particular room, it would be better to get the date interval of room usage. Also I have comprehended the absence of opportunity of displaying the order table would not be a norm. So here's the list of fields I should display:

1. the client name
2. the storey number
3. the quantity of places
4. the other specific
5. the price
6. the date of settling
7. the date of eviction
8. id of the row in order database table (invisible)

I suppose it wouldn't be problematically, but here's other tables I have:

```
$CR5="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, id_storeys INTEGER, id_places INTEGER, id_type INTEGER)";
$CR6="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, id_client INTEGER, id_room INTEGER, price FLOAT(10), start_time DATETIME, finish_time DATETIME);";
```

So I should display specific columns and here's my attempt:

```
SELECT order1.id, order1.price, order1.start_time, order1.finish_time, client.pib, storeys.characteristic AS ch1, places.characteristic AS ch2, type.characteristic AS ch3 
FROM order1, client, storeys, places, type;
```

There's no error. But the amount of rows in HTML table is too high. The table had to display one row only because there are one row in order1 and one row in room exclusively. Instead of that it shows 4 rows probably because of the quantity of rows in the tables client, storeys, places and type is sometimes more than 1.

I have no idea how to write down the query. But there are two requirements:

1. The number of rows in HTML table should equal to the amount of rows in order1 and in room.
2. The table must contain only the data that is present in room and order1.

And in addition, I have not used any relationships in database yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Simple answer: learn about `JOIN` in SQL. Right now you're doing a default cross-join which matches all rows in all tables to each other. You need to explicitly `INNER JOIN` and explicitly specify which column in each table should match to which column in the joined table. Take a tutorial, there are dozens available for free onlione.

Comment: Ok. I'll take it into account.